# No se crean todos los campos de mi tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer un `CREATE TABLE` que resulte de la consulta de 2 tablas distintas. Lo que deseo saber es el número de productos que tiene cada usuario. ¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
            usuarios
            --------
            id | nombre_usuario 

            productos 
            ---------
            id_producto | id_usuario | nombre_producto | tipo_producto
```

Comment: Me imagino que estás en el proceso de crear una respuesta. Pero por favor aségurate de que la pregunta en sí quede clara. El problema, y la razón por la que se cerró la pregunta en primer lugar, es que la pregunta no incluía todos los datos necesarios para poder dar una contestación. Aun si te respondes a ti mismo, se espera que la pregunta sea de calidad.

Comment: Exactamente como dice @sstan, Matrix. Has de mejorar tambien la pregunta. Un saludo y gracias por poner la respuesta. Ya puedes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: @sstan Sí, acabo de terminar de publicar mi respuesta. Aún así, veo que la consulta sql que planteé fue borrada. Me imagino que irá en pro de las normas del sitio, de lo contrario faltaría información que yo mismo publiqué y que ahora no está. En cualquier caso, espero que mi respuesta haya sido útil. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tenemos estas 2 tablas... :

```
            usuarios
            --------
            id | nombre_usuario 

            productos 
            ---------
            id_producto | id_usuario | nombre_producto | tipo_producto
```

..Y deseamos saber cuántos productos tiene cada usuario, lo podríamos solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
            SELECT usuarios.nombre_usuario, COUNT(*) 
            AS contar FROM  usuarios 
            INNER JOIN productos ON usuarios.ID = productos.id_usuario 
            GROUP BY productos.id_usuario
```

Si deseamos obtener el resultado de la consulta anterior imaginando que el tipo de producto es "otros", añadiríamos `WHERE...`, así:

```
            SELECT usuarios.nombre_usuario, COUNT(*) 
            AS contar FROM  usuarios 
            INNER JOIN productos ON usuarios.ID = productos.id_usuario 
            WHERE tipo_producto = 'otros'
            GROUP BY productos.id_usuario
```

Finalmente, si deseamos crear una tabla con los resultados de esa consulta, solo tenemos que añadir `CREATE TABLE nombre_de_la_tabla` delante de la consulta. Saludos y espero que sea útil mi pregunta-respuesta.